# How to split incrementally part of dataframe that in memory to R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, out-of-memory, bigdata

I have a bigdata dataset (`dat1`)

```
require (data.table)
dat1 <- fread('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/poker/poker-hand-testing.data')
```

I split it into 1000 subdatasets:

```
chunk <- 1000 ## No. of rows per chunk
n <- nrow(dat1)
r  <- rep(1:floor(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
d <- split(dat1,r)
```

I would like to create a new list of accumulative subdatasets. So that each member in the list will include the lines of the former member and a delta of `d[i+1]`:

```
e<-list()
e[[1]]<-d[[1]]
for (i in 1:997 ) {e[[i+1]]<-bind_rows(e[[i]],d[[i+1]])}
```

After running a while I get the following:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.8 Mb in R
```

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.0 Mb

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Hebrew_Israel.1255  LC_CTYPE=Hebrew_Israel.1255    LC_MONETARY=Hebrew_Israel.1255
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Hebrew_Israel.1255    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] dplyr_0.5.0            rpart_4.1-10           partykit_1.1-1         plyr_1.8.4             caret_6.0-76          
 [6] ggplot2_2.2.1          lattice_0.20-34        data.table_1.10.4      arulesSequences_0.2-17 arules_1.5-0          
[11] Matrix_1.2-7.1        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.11       RWeka_0.4-34       visNetwork_1.0.3   assertthat_0.2.0   digest_0.6.12      foreach_1.4.3     
 [7] R6_2.2.1           MatrixModels_0.4-1 stats4_3.3.2       RWekajars_3.9.1-3  rlang_0.1.1        lazyeval_0.2.0    
[13] curl_2.6           SparseM_1.77       rstudioapi_0.6     minqa_1.2.4        car_2.1-4          nloptr_1.0.4      
[19] DiagrammeR_0.9.0   splines_3.3.2      lme4_1.1-13        stringr_1.2.0      htmlwidgets_0.8    igraph_1.0.1      
[25] munsell_0.4.3      influenceR_0.1.0   rgexf_0.15.3       mgcv_1.8-15        htmltools_0.3.6    nnet_7.3-12       
[31] tibble_1.3.3       gridExtra_2.2.1    codetools_0.2-15   XML_3.98-1.7       viridisLite_0.2.0  MASS_7.3-45       
[37] ModelMetrics_1.1.0 nlme_3.1-128       jsonlite_1.5       gtable_0.2.0       DBI_0.6-1          magrittr_1.5      
[43] RMOAjars_1.0       scales_0.4.1       stringi_1.1.5      reshape2_1.4.2     viridis_0.4.0      RMOA_1.1          
[49] brew_1.0-6         Formula_1.2-1      data.tree_0.7.0    RColorBrewer_1.1-2 iterators_1.0.8    tools_3.3.2       
[55] Rook_1.1-1         survival_2.39-5    pbkrtest_0.4-7     parallel_3.3.2     colorspace_1.3-2   rJava_0.9-9       
[61] quantreg_5.33
```

Comment: This seems strange... 1.8 Mb is not that big.

Comment: For example `a <- 1:(10^9)` takes a second or two to create but is about  `3.7 Gb`. How much RAM do you have? Also, could you give us `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: `d <- split(dat1,1000)` does not split the data table to a 1000 subsets

Comment: @ Joseph Wood, Just added

Comment: Can you produce what you want to accomplish with a smaller data set. For instance, try it with the `mtcars` data set first.

Comment: No, I need to use it on a bigdata dataset. I works fine till it stucks.

Comment: @Avi, I don't know how it works, but if you use `split(dat1, 1000)`, it will create a list of which the first element named `1000`  is the whole `dat1`. Perhaps you are trying something like `split(dat1, rep(1:ceiling(n/1000),each = 1000))`.

Comment: Yes. Please see it in the my code. I copy paste something else. The error is relevant.

Comment: My memory size is 8Gb and only R is opened. About 7G is used...